# Gradient Descent for Logistic Regression stopped before all weights are re-assigned from initial guess

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a logistic regression classification in MATLAB and am stuck with calculating the correct weights using gradient descent.

I am using a stochastic approach, so i update each weight in the vector of weights individually    for each feature and then move onto the next sample and do again.

I am using the update equation

theta_j := theta_j - alpha * (y_i - h_theta(x_i)) * x_ij

and i break when the difference between the last weight vector and the current one is less than 0.00005. I calculate the "difference" between the two vectors by subtracting one from the other and then taking the square root of the dot product of their difference vector.

The problem is that it seems to stop updating after only four updates, so only the first four of my 8 row weight vector is even updated at all. This happens no matter what my learning rate, alpha, is.

Here is my implementation:

```
function weightVector = logisticWeightsByGradientDescentStochastic(trueClass,features)
    %% This function attemps to converge on the best set of weights for a logistic regression order 1
    %% Input:
    % trueClass - the training data's vector of true class values
    % features
    %% Output:
    % weightVector - vector of size n+1 (n is number of features)
    % corresponding to convergent weights

    %% Create one vector and append to features
    oneVector = ones( size(features,1) , 1); %create one vector to append to features
    regressData = horzcat(oneVector, features); % create dataset that we will use to calculate regression weights

    %% Get Data Size
    dataSize = size(regressData);

    %% Initial pick for weightVector
    weightVector = rand( dataSize(2), 1); %create a zero vector equal to size of regressData
    weightVector = 100.*weightVector

    %% Choose learning Rate
    learningRate = 1000;

    %% Stochastic Gradient Descent

    oldWeightVector = weightVector; %set oldWeightVector
    newWeightVector = oldWeightVector; % pre-allocate size for newWeightVector
    difference = Inf; %initial difference to get into loop
    iterCount = 0; %for testing to see how long it takes

    while(difference > 0.000005)

        for m=1:dataSize(1) %for all samples

            for n=1:dataSize(2) %for all features

                %% calculate Sigmoid predicted 
                predictedClass = evaluateSigmoid(oldWeightVector, regressData(m,:))


                %% Calculate the error
                error = learningRate .* (trueClass(m) - predictedClass) .* regressData(m,n);

                %% Update weightVector for feature n
                newWeightVector(n) = oldWeightVector(n) - error;

                %% Calculate difference
                vectorDifference = newWeightVector - oldWeightVector; %find difference vector between new and old weight vectors
                difference = sqrt( dot( vectorDifference, vectorDifference)) %calculate the magnitude of difference between new and old weight vectors

                iterCount = iterCount + 1;

                %%Break if difference is below threshold
                if(difference < 0.00005)
                    break
                else
                    oldWeightVector = newWeightVector; % update Old Weight Vector for next prediction
                end
            end %for n

            %%Break if difference is below threshold
            if(difference < 0.000005)
                break
            end   

        end %for m

    end %while difference > 0.0005

    weightVector = newWeightVector
    iterCount
end
```

I have also tried doing a global method instead of stochastic, but it still results in extremely large weight values.

Here is my evaluateSigmoid function

```
function logisticPrediciton = evaluateSigmoid(weightVector, sample)
    %% This function evaluates the sigmoid with a given weight vector and sample
    %% Input:
    % weightVector - column  vector of n weights
    % sample - row vector sample with n-1 features (a 1 will be appended to the
    % beginning for the constant weight

    sample = transpose(sample); % sample is fed in as a row vector, so must be transposed

    exponent = exp( transpose(weightVector) * sample);

    logisticPrediciton = 1 ./ ( 1 + exponent);


end
```

[And here is the data set i am working with.](http://pastebin.com/wdq3KyGf) The last column is filtered out, and the first column is turned into 1 or zero based on if it meets a threshold (below 22 is 0, above is 1).

Comment: two general points that you should first look at: the logistic function is defined as 1/(1+e(-X)). Second it is common to stop when the error converged to a certain point and not the weights.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected my sigmoid but now it is stopping after one iteration. I know why it is doing this. The first time it computers error it seems to get the same value as the true class (even though there should be some difference), and as such the result of the error is zero, and that means that the newWeightVector becomes the oldWeightVector minus zero, so it is the same and the loop stops. How do i correct for this obvious fault? Checking to see if the error has converged wouldn't necessarily stop this if if guesses the correct class twice in a row.

Comment: again, do not stop based on weights but instead stop based on how close it is to your true data. also the function of error is learningRate*predictedClass*(1-predictedClass)*(trueClass(m)-predictedClass)